# How to assign data to EditorFor using TempData or ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, viewbag

I want to assign `EST_ID` from **index.cshtml** to **Create.cshtml** view which uses `Html.Editorfor(model=>model.EST_ID)`.

how to assign `EST_ID` to `Html.Editorfor(model=>model.EST_ID)` using TempData or ViewBag by getting `EST_ID` from table in index.cshtml?

**Here's my controller code**

```
public ActionResult Publication(int id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string est = db.EstimateHeaders.Find(id).ToString();
        ViewBag.EST_ID=est;
        return RedirectToAction("Create", "EP");
    }
    return View();
}
```

**Here's Create.cshtml code**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.EST_ID,
    htmlAttributes : new { @placeholder="EST_ID",
                           @class = "form-control",
                           @readonly = "readonly",
                           @required = "required" } )
```

How to assign `EST_ID` value from **index.cshtml** to **create.cshtml** EditorFor?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your example.

First, `EditorFor` needs a non-dynamic expression so you can't use ViewBag or ViewModel directly. Assign the value to a variable if you don't want to use proper View Models.

```
@{
    var id = ViewBag.EST_ID;
}

@Html.EditorFor(m => id)
```

Next, you cannot to pass the value through ViewBag to a different action. You don't show your Create action and unless you explicitly assign `ViewBag.EST_ID` again, the value will be null.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.EST_ID = est;
    return View();
}
```

To pass a vaule from **Publication** to **Create** through redirection, you'll need to use query string parameters or use TempData.

```
public ActionResult Publication(int id)
{
    string est = ...;
    // TempData.EST_ID = est;   // pass with TempData

    // or use routeValues passed as query string params
    return RedirectToAction("Create", "EP", routeValues: new { est = est });
}

public ActionResult Create(string est)
{
    ViewBag.EST_ID = est;
    // or if set previously
    //   ViewBag.EST_ID = TempData.EST_ID;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: i followed your answer, but i am getting `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies....` as value in view

Comment: i changed `string est = db.EstimateHeaders.Find(id).ToString();` to `string est = db.EstimateHeaders.Find(id).EST_ID.ToString();` everything works flawless. Thankyou!!!